# Why is this very basic StreamGeometry (a square) not rendering in a Window's OnRender?

Tags: wpf, onrender

Ok, I'm stumped.  Why is this not rendering the square? (Note, I purposely used positive and negative coordinates so it would display regardless of the origin. Didn't know if the x/y were reversed, etc.)

```
public partial class Main : Window
{
    StreamGeometry _cueGeometry;
    Brush          _cueBrush;
    Pen            _cuePen;

    public Main()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        _cueGeometry = new StreamGeometry();
        using (var geometryContext = _cueGeometry.Open())
        {
            geometryContext.BeginFigure(new Point( 40, 40), true, true);
            geometryContext.LineTo     (new Point( 40,-40), true, true);
            geometryContext.LineTo     (new Point(-40,-40), true, true);
            geometryContext.LineTo     (new Point(-40, 40), true, true);
        }
        _cueGeometry.Freeze();

        _cueBrush = Brushes.AliceBlue;

        _cuePen = new Pen(Brushes.Gray, 1);
        _cuePen.Freeze();

    }

    protected override void OnRender(DrawingContext dc)
    {
        base.OnRender(dc);
        dc.DrawGeometry(_cueBrush, _cuePen, _cueGeometry);
    }

}
```

### Update

I've noticed something else odd.  If I move this code to a subclass of Panel with a red background, it renders the red background then renders a blue square with a gray border in front of it. (Note: it's not clipped to the bounds of the control which is how I can see all of that square.)

If however, I simply change the subclass to UserControl, the blue square with a gray border renders behind the red control.  (Again, I can see this because I have clipping disabled.)

If finally I change it to a subclass of Control, I no longer get the red background and *only* get the blue square with a gray border.  This I take it is because Control doesn't do any rendering on its own, but still doesn't explain why the background color is rendering over my drawing in a UserControl as opposed to the Panel.  My guess is there's some element that's part of a template that's appearing in front of what's rendered, but I can't think what that would be.

Answer (score 1):

Found it.  The default template for a window has a border in the content area who had an opaque white background, obstructing the rendering.  Using Snoop, I found the border, changed the visibility to 'Hidden' and sure enough, there was the rendered path.

Mystery solved!

Answer (score 0):

Or simply set the Window's `Background` to `Transparent` or `{x:Null}`.